# Is there a way to show the emma code coverage percentage in the terminal?

Tags: java, maven, terminal, code-coverage, emma

I would like to see the emma code coverage percentage in the terminal, when I execute

```
mvn emma:emma
```

I don't need the full report. Just the code coverage percentage of project is enough for me.

Is it possible?

Tks,
Pablo Cantero

Comment: not as far as the official documentation is concerned: http://emma.sourceforge.net/maven-emma-plugin/goals.html   Would be a nice feature. Where can we add this feature request?